# Get impresions count from today, yesterday and this month, Impresionist gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, impressions

I am using gem called `impressionist` to log page views on show action.

Everythink works just great.I can get number of all pageviews with:

```
@advertisement.impression_count
```

But now I want to be able filter pageviews per today, yesterday and this month.

So far I came up with this solution.

```
 @today  =  Impression.where( :conditions => { :created_at => Date.today...Date.today+1 }, :impresionable_id =>@advertisement.id)
```

There is no errors.

Then In view:

```
<%= "#{@today} views so far!" %>
```

gives me `#<Impression::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000068d46f8>`

then I tried to add like : `<%= "#{@today.impression_count} views so far!" %>` gives me this :

```
undefined method `impression_count'
```

then I tried just  :`<%= "#{@today.count} views so far!" %>` and still error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'conditions.created_at' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `impressions`  WHERE (`conditions`.`created_at` >= '2014-12-18' AND `conditions`.`created_at` < '2014-12-19') AND `impressions`.`impresionable_id` = 127
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for the conditions hash.

```
today = Date.today
range = today..today.next_day
@imp = Impression.where(created_at: range, impressionable_id: @advertisement.id)
```

And if an `@advertisement` can have impressions, then the following would be better:

```
@imp = @advertisement.impressions.where(created_at: range)
```

Then to get the count, you must:

```
@today = @imp.count
```

Also, just FYI, you might need to use `DateTime.now` instead of `Date.today` because you're comparing with a datetime field i.e. created_at.

Answer (score 2):

```
@today = Impression.where( :conditions => { :created_at => Date.today...Date.today+1 }, :impresionable_id =>@advertisement.id)
```

returns a `#<Impression::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000068d46f8>`.

Try this:

```
@today = Impression.where(created_at: Date.today...Date.today+1, impresionable_id: @advertisement.id).count
```

Comment: I got this error :Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'impressions.impresionable_id'

Comment: Minor misprint there. Should be `impressions.impressionable_id` ... otherwise works great.

Answer (score 2):

Add scopes in **impression.rb**

```
scope :today, -> {where("created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.end_of_day)}
scope :yesterday, -> {where("created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?", 1.day.ago.beginning_of_day, 1.day.ago.end_of_day)}
scope :this_month, -> {where("created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_month, Time.now.end_of_month)}
```

in Controller:

```
 @today = Impression.today.where(impresionable_id: @advertisement.id)
 @yesterday = Impression.yesterday.where(impresionable_id: @advertisement.id)
 @this_month = Impression.this_month.where(impresionable_id: @advertisement.id)
```

And you can use these scopes anywhere you need to filter `Impressions` by date today, yesterday or this month. It's better compared to writing the `where` clause everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have impression model ? In that example there wasn't/

Comment: `Impression.where...` says you have it. Anyway, just clone it from the gem or create one and inherit methods from the Impression model of the gem.

Comment: This is the content of the impression.rb :) https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/blob/master/app/models/impression.rb  so you just need to create an impression.rb file in app/models and put scopes there.. app will use this one.

Comment: Ok, I did like you said. But I got this error: `undefined method `today' for #<Class:0x00000007a8b680>` in Advertisement controller ! It seems that scopes not working :(

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I though

In advertisement.rb

```
 has_many :impressions, :as=>:impressionable


     def view_count_yesterday
       impressions.where("created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?",                 1.day.ago.beginning_of_day, 1.day.ago.end_of_day).size

     end

      def view_count_today
        impressions.where("created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.end_of_day).size
               # impressionist_count(:start_date => 1.day.ago)
     end
```